# My Jupyter notebook shows an error 'connecting to kernel '. I dont know what to do?

Tags: python, kernel

I am not to able to run codes on my  Jupyter notebook.It shows connecting to kernel and then shows not connected. Same with spyder and those connected with Anaconda.

```
This is the log of the notebook
[I 15:46:35.196 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 15:46:35.215 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 15:46:35.322 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\mm
[I 15:46:35.322 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 15:46:35.323 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=53a396a048abbd68e66ad5dcf1cdacef2aab87ef7b8aa2b7
[I 15:46:35.323 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=53a396a048abbd68e66ad5dcf1cdacef2aab87ef7b8aa2b7
[I 15:46:35.323 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 15:46:35.602 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/mm/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3080-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=53a396a048abbd68e66ad5dcf1cdacef2aab87ef7b8aa2b7
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=53a396a048abbd68e66ad5dcf1cdacef2aab87ef7b8aa2b7
[W 15:47:27.021 NotebookApp] Notebook Assignment_DBSCAN.ipynb is not trusted
[I 15:47:28.255 NotebookApp] Kernel started: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 112, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "C:\Users\mm\code.py", line 40
    mul_lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg',max_iter =1000)
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[I 15:47:31.156 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 112, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "C:\Users\mm\code.py", line 40
    mul_lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg',max_iter =1000)
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[I 15:47:34.190 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 112, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "C:\Users\mm\code.py", line 40
    mul_lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg',max_iter =1000)
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[I 15:47:37.202 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 112, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "C:\Users\mm\code.py", line 40
    mul_lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg',max_iter =1000)
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[I 15:47:40.234 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 112, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "C:\Users\mm\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "C:\Users\mm\code.py", line 40
    mul_lr = linear_model.LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='newton-cg',max_iter =1000)
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[W 15:47:43.264 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 15:47:43.264 NotebookApp] Kernel a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be died, removing from map.
[W 15:47:49.307 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be:58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020
[W 15:48:13.422 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be:58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020
[W 15:48:28.368 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be
[E 15:48:28.373 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be)
[W 15:48:28.378 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be/channels?session_id=58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020 (::1): Kernel does not exist: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be
[W 15:48:28.455 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be/channels?session_id=58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020 (::1) 39147.31ms referer=None
[W 15:48:28.457 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be/channels?session_id=58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020 (::1): Kernel does not exist: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be
[W 15:48:28.464 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be/channels?session_id=58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020 (::1) 15044.70ms referer=None
[W 15:48:32.499 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be:58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020
[W 15:49:00.539 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be:58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020
[W 15:49:36.554 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be:58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020
[W 15:50:28.588 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be:58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020
[I 15:51:44.444 NotebookApp] 302 GET /notebooks/Untitled11.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 (::1) 2.99ms
[W 15:51:52.595 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be:58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020
[W 15:56:53.025 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: a993bb8f-8adc-45f8-a5ca-833913a566be:58c6e2286d514efba8596e9d46e58020
```

Comment: Looks more like a system/config issue. I would check your Jupyter installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a messed up environment, probably due to a globally set PYTHONPATH. It includes your folder `c:\Users\mm`, which makes `pdb` import the file `code.py` in that folder instead of [the package with the same name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html). Remove the entry `c:\Users\mm` from your PYTHONPATH.